# How could I simultaneously control two PCs from a third?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse

I have two windows PCs that I want to *simultaneously* control from a third.
ie I want the position of the mouse of PC A and PC B to exactly match the position and clicks of the mouse on PC C

Why? I have software on the two PCs that I want to trigger at the same time and having a third PC will make the process easier than having multiple people on each of the computers.

Comment: Seems like you need to automate the tasks where they both start at the same time

Comment: Dave sounds right, having a basic script saying "start XYZ at exactly n:yy time" should be infinitely easier, and probably start at a more synchronized time too.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find it, but I finally remembered a piece of software that does exactly what you're talking about (sort of).  Synergy allows you to control multiple computers as if they are one.  It's intended to make multiple computers work as multiple monitors, but I wouldn't be surprised if you could get it set up to mirror your movements across the computers.

https://symless.com/synergy